# Can you calculate the average transitivity for a list of graph objects?

Tags: r, igraph

I've made a list of 1000 random networks to compare to a network. I would like to calculate the average measures for them, including transitivity(), reciprocity() and mean_distance(). Here is the code I used to make the list

```
set.seed(1)
nwl <- list()
for (x in seq_len(1000L)) {
    Start = sample(18, 693, replace=TRUE)
    End   = sample(18, 693, replace=TRUE)
    df = data.frame(Start, End)
    nwl[[x]]= graph_from_data_frame(df, directed=TRUE)
}
```

I can calculate each graph's individual transitivity like this.

```
transitivity(nwl[[x]])
```

Where x = the graph number from the list. Is there a way to take the mean of all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
sapply(nwl, transitivity)
```

to get the values, and

```
mean(sapply(nwl, transitivity))
# [1] 0.9862236
```

to get the mean.

Comment: Okay, will do. My apologies